# Easy HDD recovery that functions like OEM recovery

Tags: windows, restore

I have no problem recovering my own hard drive from a backup... I just have an extra hard drive that is a copy of my main hard drive exactly as it was right after I installed my OS and programs.  This way I can just plug the extra hard drive in, boot to Ghost, and restore.

The problem is with other people.  Most people whose computers I work on cannot handle this "complex" restore procedure themselves.

I need a program that I can install on the computers of my customers that will provide the OEM style functionality of "restoring to out of box state" with **a few simple clicks**.  The program **should restore from a partition on the same drive** that is being restored... just like the OEM style restores programs.

What software can do this... possibly some Acronis product?

Comment: ...and after that you'd still have to come in to restore documents, images, messages, ...? [Good luck](http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/frustrations/388b/)! ;-)

Comment: You really want your customers to wipe out all their data in a few clicks?

Comment: @Arjan no, I don't keep any of my data on my main drive, I have a NFS which contains all of my document, music, photos, etc.  As for my customers data I simply advise them to save everything they want to save to a flash drive, then they can put it back on after the restore... I think that is simple enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Acronis® True Image™ Home 2011](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) can do this.
You can even install it to run of a keypress at boot. (F11 I think)
Restoring from the recovery partition is a few simple clicks with minimal options for the end user to mess up. I use the business version for re-imaging machines at work, its pretty slick, the home version is very similar just made a bit easier for the users.

Comment: I liked both Paragon and Acronis, but Acronis seems to be a bit more simple, and that is what I am going for here.  I only tested for a short bit, but it seemed to work well, contrary to what I read about Acronis in many forums.  If I run into data corruption issues I will probably switch to Paragon like many of the people in the forums did.

Answer (score 1):

A free option is [Paragon Backup & Recovery 2010 Free Advanced](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/db-express/).

Comment: I'm going to try both Paragon Backup and Acronis True Image out to see which one works best.